# Intellij find usages by package from method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can't find anything on this and sort of would like a report on it and not going through all of this code. Here's the question.

I am analyzing a method that calls about 45 other methods that calls other methods. I need to find out all calls that ends up with a specific package from this specific method. How could I do this?

An option I have is to to use "call hierarchy" and drill down one method at a time (but there is no filter option as I can see to just see methods from one given package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do filtering when using the call hierarchy (CTRL - ALT - H). On the newly opened pane, there is a drop-down list with the name "Scope:". Here you can add a new scope where you can include/exclude filter not only on packages but also on classes or to search given a certain regex.

I checked this on the latest Intellij version (14.1.5).